# Representing multiple values in delimited seperated value file

Tags: export-to-excel, export-to-csv, openoffice-calc, csv

Currently i'm working on transforming a xml file to delimited seperated file.I was pondering over the idea of representing multiple values of an attribute field..Currently my idea is to represent the values as below:
`First Name;Last Name;E-mail id;Description`

```
Fresher;user1;"|email1@abc.com|;|email2@abc.com|";This user joined as fresher.
```

My question is;Is there is a standard followed for representation of multiple values.?
How is this scenario taken care in common spreadsheet programs available such as Microsoft excel,openoffice calc and lotus notes 123 when imported into .csv file..??
Based on this i want to make changes to my xslt code..
Appreciate any help in this regard..

Answer (score 0):

According to my experiences it is always good to stick to database normalisation standards. There are a lot of information everywhere in the web for further references.

a) When looking in your proposal what I like is to separate each column with semicolon instead of comma. It's easier to import data to any system later especially when you will deal with different (national) standards of number separation symbols

b) However, which I don't like is the 'e-mail' section. There would be a problem in the following areas:

1. quotation marks are problems- try to avoid them.
2. don't separate inside e-mail addresses with the same mark as for column separation. Therefore you shouldn't use semicolon there (what I guess- you can have one or few e-mails for each record).

If you can't introduce database normalisation standards I would propose the following small improvements to your idea:

```
Fresher;user1;email1@abc.com|email2@abc.com;This user joined as fresher
```

If you provide that kind of data file I think each of vba user would be able to import it to Excel (or any other system) easily and quickly.

Comment: Currently my code handles semicolon as delimiter,in which case your above proposed changes will work.Later i'm thinking about having no restriction on the delimiter character being used and on the data of each columns.. What i mean is if i use single pipe(|) itself as delimiter,then there would be a problem.Both from readability point of view and as well if i try to parse the same csv file to extract data for my use.                                                  In that case what further changes do i make?

Comment: I'am not sure if I get what you mean in last comment. What is my doubt in your example is the 'e-mail addresses columns'- does it have constant numbers of elements? Anyway, you can use any 'unique' combination of delimiter character if only they are...'unique', which means and not used in data column.